# std::string declared function does not complain returning char *

Tags: c++, string

This is not my program so don't start berating me :-). Some random program I got. A globally declared buffer is being returned by MyFunc(). I use VS2008 and it does not complain

```
static char buffer[1024];

std::string MyFunc() {
    ....
    ....
    return buffer;
}
```

However when I add this line of code

```
char * ret;
ret = MyFunc()
```

It complains: "error: no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "char *" exists"

My question is why is the compiler complaining now? Why this inconstancy in syntax checking? Again I dont have the freedom to change MyFunc(). In my program if I can make

```
std::string ret;
ret = MyFunc();
```

and get rid of the syntax error but would really like to understand this strange behavior.

Comment: Because it would not make sense to allow `char*` access to the contents of a `string`.

Comment: writing `ret = MyFunc();` is assigning the return value (with the appropriate return type) to "ret". According to the function definition, you told the compiler that `MyFunc` was going to return a `std::string` (which in your case has a constructor which accepts a `char*`) - hence your `return` statement did not barf.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the inundation of the reasons for this compiler behavior. Thanks to all I am in the light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the syntax, it is the structure of the `std::string` that makes the compiler behave differently.

When you are returning a `char*` from a function returning `std::string`, the compiler notices that there is a constructor of `std::string` that takes `char*`, calls that constructor, and quietly returns the result.

When you are trying to return a `std::string` from a `char*` - returning function, the compiler tries to see if there is a conversion operator to make `char*` from a `std::string`, finds that there is no such operator, and reports an error.

If you want to convert a string to `char*`, you need to make a copy of the string's buffer, like this:

```
char* ret_ch = new char[ret.size()+1];
memcpy(ret_ch, ret.c_str(), ret.size()+1);
return ret_ch;
```

You could think that it is OK to return `c_str()` by itself, but it is *not* a good idea: the buffer that "backs up" this C string belongs to `std::string` object, so once the string gets deallocated, accessing the buffer starts producing undefined behavior. That is why you need to make an explicit copy when you access the buffer of a string. Of course you are also responsible for calling `delete[]` on the copied result.

Answer (score 7):

string() has a constructor that accepts a char*, so you get an automatic conversion. There is no automatic conversion from a string to a char*. You have to call string::c_str() to get the char*.

***Edit***
Although you asked only for an explanation of the behavior, others in this forum seem to think I have short-changed you by not mentioning that string::c_str returns a const char*, not a simple char*. But the explanation remains: there is no implicit/automatic conversion from string to char* or const char*. Feel free to read about c_str [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) if it's important to you.

Comment: And all along I though the question was why it is this way. And you can't get `char*` from `stding::c_str()` by the way.

Comment: Because there is no constructor for char*, and particularly not a constructor that accepts a string. Did you think that was the answer the OP was requesting?

Comment: @juanchopanza What are you talking about? Read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)

Comment: @GreatBigBore, That's a `const char *`. It isn't compatible with `ret`.

Comment: No, I thought they were after the reason why there is an implicit conversion one way, and not the other. Not how this is implemented.

Comment: @chris He's clearly new to c++; I didn't think the const aspect was important to his question.

Comment: @GreatBigBore It is important. Later, when he attempts to modify the string through the pointer, he'll ask another question.

Comment: @faranwath I quote the OP: "would really like to understand this strange behavior". I could have tried to explain life, the universe, and everything, but he wasn't asking for that.

Comment: @GreatBigBore Yeah, but that's an easy one: just type 42 and you're done.

Comment: Let peace be on earth and programming :-) Thanks to all again for the answers. GreatBigBore special thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` is designed as implicitly constructable from `char const*` because this supports using string literals and typical C style code strings as initializer values.

If this was not supported then one would just have to use some intermediate function, which would add nothing but verbosity and inefficiency.

In the other direction, however, `std::string` is *intentionally* designed to not convert implicitly to `char const*`. Part of the rationale is probably that <del>with `std::string` being logically mutable,</del> the returned raw pointer is only valid as long as no operations are performed that might cause a buffer replacement or string destruction. For example,

```
    char const* s = foo().c_str();
```

where `foo` produces a `std::string`, makes `s` point to a buffer that no longer exists, a ***dangling pointer*** that is invalid.

The `c_str()` member function call makes the conversion stand out.

Consider how more common that problem could be if one could write just

```
    char const* s = foo();
```

and have that compile.

---

<sup>Regarding that strike-through (deleted) text, I realized that it's completely irrelevant whether the string is logically mutable or immutable. Sorry. Need more coffee!</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the full clarification Cheers :-)